# C# Producer-Consumer using Semaphores

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer

Inspired by The Little Book of Semaphores, I decided to implement the Producer-Consumer problem using Semaphores.

I specifically want to be able to stop all Worker threads at will.
I've tested my methodolodgy extensively and can't find anything faulty.

Following code is a prototype for testing and can be ran as a Console application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;

public class ProducerConsumer
{
    private static readonly int _numThreads = 5;
    private static readonly int _numItemsEnqueued = 10;
    private static readonly Semaphore _workItems = new Semaphore(0, int.MaxValue);
    private static readonly ManualResetEvent _stop = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ConcurrentQueue<int> _queue;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();

        // Create and start threads.
        for (int i = 1; i <= _numThreads; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Worker));

            // Start the thread, passing the number.
            t.Start(i);
        }

        // Wait for half a second, to allow all the
        // threads to start and to block on the semaphore.
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Main thread adds {0} items to the queue and calls Release() {0} times.", _numItemsEnqueued));
        for (int i = 1; i <= _numItemsEnqueued; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waking up a worker thread.");
            _queue.Enqueue(i);
            _workItems.Release(); //wake up 1 worker
            Thread.Sleep(2000); //sleep 2 sec so it's clear the threads get unblocked 1 by 1
        }

        // sleep for 5 seconds to allow threads to exit
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Assert.True(_queue.Count == 0);

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread stops all threads.");
        _stop.Set();

        // wait a while to exit
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread exits.");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Last value of Semaphore was {0}.", _workItems.Release()));
        Assert.True(_queue.Count == 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Worker(object num)
    {
        // Each worker thread begins by requesting the semaphore.
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} begins and waits for the semaphore.", num);
        WaitHandle[] wait = { _workItems, _stop };
        int signal;
        while (0 == (signal = WaitHandle.WaitAny(wait)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} becomes unblocked by Release() and has work to do.", num);
            int res;
            if (_queue.TryDequeue(out res))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} dequeues {1}.", num, res);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("this should not happen.");
            }
        }

        if (signal == 1)
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} was stopped.", num);

        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} exits.", num);
    }
}
```

Now for my question, I'm using `WaitHandle.WaitAny(semaphore)` under the assumption that when I call `Release()` on the semaphore, only 1 Worker will be woken up. However, I can't find reassurance in the documentation that this is actually true. Can anyone confirm this is true?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point.

Comment: You should use `SemaforSlim`, it's faster. Also you can investigate [`TPL Dataflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601.aspx) library for this task, you may level the amount of workers with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property, or dispose the link between two blocks to stop pipeline completely

Comment: Thanks @VMAtm, will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed interesting that it seems that the documentation doesn't state explicitly that in the case of `WaitOne` only 1 thread will receive the signal. When you get familiar with multithreading theory this becomes somewhat self-evident.

Yes, `WaitOne` that is called on `Semaphore` (and `WaitAny` that is called on a list of `WaitHandle`s that include `Semaphore`) is received by a single thread. If you want reference from MSDN so here it is, `Semaphore` is child class of `WaitHandle`, [which is:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Encapsulates operating system–specific objects that wait for **exclusive access** to shared resources.

So yes, unless explicitly stated methods provide exclusive access.

For example method `WaitOne` of `ManualResetEvent` will unblock for all waiting threads, [but documentation is explicit about it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Notifies **one or more** waiting threads that an event has occurred.

Comment: Thanks, it's the answer that I was expecting. It was because of the behaviour of `ManualResetEvent` that I wanted reassurance on the behaviour of `Semaphore`, so great that you included it.